# hwinfo locks and creates load

Tags: linux, hanging

Every night we run hwinfo to dump the current hardware infos into a file.

Today we had a constant load of 5:

```
top - 13:24:32 up 5 days, 19:35,  3 users,  load average: 5,08, 5,20, 5,31
Tasks: 258 total,   1 running, 257 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0,0 us,  0,2 sy,  0,1 ni, 99,3 id,  0,4 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   8174748 total,  7394184 used,   780564 free,   427664 buffers
KiB Swap:  2097148 total,   856972 used,  1240176 free,  5193064 cached
```

There were 5 hwinfo commands running. One for this night, one for yesterday, one for the night before yesterday ....

I could not see these commands with `top` or `iotop`.

Which tool instead of `top` could be used, so that I can see the hanging `hwinfo` processes the next time?

After killing the hwinfo processes to load settled immediately.

If you know why the load created by the hwinfo command is not visible in `top`, then please leave a comment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`top` sorted by CPU may not find something stuck in I/O or something and doing little CPU. Try hitting `i` in top to enable the idle filter hiding states of sleeping or idle.

As to `hwinfo`, tricky without seeing what it is caught on. If you see this again, try tracing the process to see what it is doing.  One way: `ltrace -S -o /tmp/hwinfo -p $(pidof hwinfo)`   This last file it read may be interesting, for example.

Load average is simply proportional to the number of tasks in a ready to run state. It does not create load; these may be doing a lot or a little.  However, a high load average usually indicates some resource shortage or contention. Whether that is a symptom of an actual problem is up to you. There were 5 running before you noticed.

Comment: Today hwinfo was hanging again. I did `ltrace -S -o /tmp/hwinfo -p 20089` and then ltrace was hanging, too. The file "/tmp/hwinfo" was empty. I tried to kill the ltrace process, but this failed. Only "kill -9" terminated the ltrace process.

Comment: Review syslog and dmesg for anything interesting. Consider calling your hwinfo via ltrace so it attaches immediately: `ltrace -S -o /tmp/hwinfo  hwinfo`